# How to set AWS Glue proxy settings

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm trying to set proxy inside glue script in order to connect to external source - snowflake .
But none of the below worked

Approach 1 : Added proxy to the env variable

```
os.environ['USE_PROXY'] = 'true'
os.environ['http_proxy'] = '<>'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = '<>'
```

Approach 2 : Added proxy in spark context

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions = <>
```

I observed the container IP has been changing hence snowflake rejecting the connection ...

Err mesg
`An error occurred while calling o582.load. IP <> is not allowed to access Snowflake. Contact your local security administrator.`

** AWS Glue connections cannot b used in this case because of security issues ....

Comment: Where are you running your Glue script? In a job or endpoint ? More about integrating it with snowflake is here https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-to-use-aws-glue-with-snowflake/